# Struck with a serious issue when upgrading to ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04

Tags: grub2

I installed ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows xp professional.  When I tried to upgrade to 13.10 from 13.04, it took some time to download and then it started cleaning the files and then message was displayed that xp cleaned (this msg was seen by my younger brother and then he cut the power off) . Now the computer when starts displays this screen and I dont know how to proceed. To anyone giving solution I would like tell you that I prefer xp over linux(personal reasons). So is there any way to get out of this problem, I neither can open xp nor linux?

Sorry, I was tensed, please understand my situation, really sorry for that, here is what I meant : This is what I am getting when I start my PC
[image: screen photo]

Comment: `... starts displays this screen...` What screen?

Comment: are you still able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 3):

If you upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 using Software Updater (formerly Update Manager) then it's probable your brother misunderstood a message and stopped your upgrade. If you were using a Live CD/USB it's possible you select a fresh install on 13.10 and were over writing your XP partition.

I recommend you use a Live CD/USB of Ubuntu and boot your system selecting the Try out Ubuntu option. Once you are in the trial session mount the partition on your hard drive to see if your XP and Ubuntu partitions are still there.

If XP is still there then you are in good shape and only need to repair your Master Boot Record (MBR). You'll want to read up about the MBR before touching it. Windows forums are probably better for that but the Linux *SystemRescueCd* has a tool to simply recover the MBR.